# Which is best Report generator(like crystalreport) for Angular6-nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, report, angular6

I am beginner in  angular6 and nodejs,   Anyone Please suggest me any 
**nodejs report generator** for ERP application. (Reports like crystal report/ssrs report in dot net)

Comment: I don't know if my answer is pertinent or not, but it look's like Crystal report manage a network tree. I suggest you to have a look to TensorFlow. I apologize if I missunderstood the purpose tho.

Comment: Thanks for comment, But actually I am searching a nodejs report generator for a ERP application.